# Unable to scrape a piece of static information from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script in python to log in a webpage using credentials and then parse a piece of information `SIGN OUT` from another link (the script is supposed to get redirected to that link) to make sure I did log in.

[Website address](https://member.angieslist.com/)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://member.angieslist.com/gateway/platform/v1/session/login"
link = "https://member.angieslist.com/"

payload = {"identifier":"usename","token":"password"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(url,json=payload,headers={
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.87 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer":"https://member.angieslist.com/member/login",
        "content-type":"application/json"
        })

    r = s.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"},allow_redirects=True)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    login_stat = soup.select_one("button[class*='menu-item--account']").text
    print(login_stat)
```

When i run the above script, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` this error which means I went somewhere wrong in my log in process as the information I wish to parse `SIGN OUT` is a static content.

***How can I parse this `SIGN OUT` information from that webpage?***

Comment: It works if you copy authenticated cookies from the browser, but you have to change the selector to `"button[id*='menu-item']"`, as it is in Tarun's answer below. It seems the API returns some elements of the required cookie, so it may be possible to create it from the json response.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion leads me to solve the issue @t.m.adam. You should post it as an answer for future readers. Btw, this is how I passed cookie within get requests headers `"Cookie": f'{"authToken="}{res.json()["authToken"]}'` taken from first requests (post).

Comment: Awesome!! I'm a little busy these days so I can't provide a proper answer, and besides that, it was you who came up with the final solution. If you don't want to give an answer, or don't want to waste the bounty rep, you could accept Tarun's answer, which also solves the problem. See you!

Comment: In fact, changing only the selector as you have suggested is enough to pull out that content if I stick to my current implementation above @t.m.adam.

Comment: Yes, it was much simpler than we thought it was. The site sets the cookies automatically, and it was only needed to change the selector. So it was basically a typo (wasn't it?), but an interesting challenge nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website requires JavaScript to work with. Though you generate the login token correctly from the login API, but when you go to the home page, it make multiple additional API calls and then updates the page.

So the issue has nothing to do with login not working. You need to use something like selenium for this

```py
from selenium import  webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://member.angieslist.com/member/login")
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("none@getnada.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("NUN@123456")
driver.find_element_by_id("login--login-button").click()
import time
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
login_stat = soup.select("[id*='menu-item']")

for item in login_stat:
    print(item.text)
print(login_stat)
driver.quit()
```

I have mixed `bs4` and `selenium` here to get it easy for you but you can use just `selenium` as well if you want

[image: Data]